# How to access superclass variable in subclass

Tags: objective-c, iphone, superclass

I have created two viewController classes such that one is superclass of another.i have a nsstring variable in superclass which i have to access in subclass please guide me how to do it. Here is my code

```
  @interface Superclass : UIViewController{
  NSString *message
  }
  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *message;
  -(id)init;
  @end


 @implementation Superclass
 @synthesize message;
 -(id)init{
{
[super init];
message=@"Hello";
return self;

 }


  @interface Subclass : Superclass{

  }

 @end


 @implementation Subclass

 - (void)viewDidLoad {

   UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:self.message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
  [super viewDidLoad];


 }
```

My alert promt but without message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you are initializing the `Subclass`?

Using `initWithNibName:bundle:` method?

In that case, your's superclass `init` method will not be called. So override `initWithNibName:bundle:` method in the super class and set the value to the variable there.

Comment: After that use 'message' with superclass' object wherever u want to access it...like superclass.message...:)

Comment: You also need to retain the message in your superclass

Comment: Thanks..Its working... Is there any method so that i can access variable directly without overriding    initWithNibName:bundle:?

Comment: Maybe add a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `super.variable` to access the super class variable.

Comment: used super.message, but with no success:(

Comment: If the subclass does not implement its own version of the property, 'self.variable' is all you need.

Comment: @jrturton.I know it.  I didn realise that he doesn have a subclass version. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

declare variable as public into super class

than

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

> ***self.message = @"something"***

, superclass's members will be inherited by subclass object